# react-native build apk for release error Get Key failed: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, build.gradle, apk

I'm trying to generate an assigned apk for production, but I'm getting this error. I've tried to generate another keystore with different passwords on macOS and Windows.

after run the command: `cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

I've got this error:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

what am I missing?

Comment: Please do not post screen shots of text output. Instead copy and paste the text directly into your question.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it's working now!

I've changed the name of the file and alias with the underline like this:

before it was => android-production.keystore

and now I've android_production and the same for the alias. I also changed the password.

Anyone knows what reason for this problem? Thanks!